# Is there a name for this structure?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I don't know what branch of math best characterizes what I'm thinking of, so I'll use a concrete example.

Suppose you have four boxes, A, B, C, D

Box A is an empty box

Box B contains Box A directly. Box A contains the contents listed above (empty)

Box C contains Box A directly, and Box B directly. Each box contains the contents listed above.

Box D contains Box A directly, Box B directly, and Box C directly. Each of those boxes contains the contents described above

Is there a name for what I'm describing here?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers#The_contemporary_standard You're effectively giving a recursive definition of the natural numbers in the standard way.

Comment: @DanielRust  Neat! =)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. It is like saying 0 ={} reads: 'a thing that contains nothing', and 1 = {{}} reads: 'a thing that contains a thing that contains nothing, and 2 = {{{}}, {}} reads: a thing that contains the thing that contains nothing, and the thing that contains the thing that contains nothing. <-- that's not an elegant wording of it - but is it the idea?

Comment: Also, why isn't {{{}}} sufficient to define 2? Is {{{}},{}} just making it explicit that 2 contains both 1 and 0?

Comment: Yep pretty much. It's the role of set theory to try and define everything in mathematics in the form of a set. This was the most natural and simple way to define the natural numbers as it only uses set union, the empty set, and induction. Of course, there are other ways to enumerate the natural numbers using these three axioms.

Comment: Your boxes are *transitive sets* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set). A transitive set is a set that contains every element that it contains *indirectly* (i.e. like $x\in A \in B$) also directly (i.e. it follows that $x\in B$).

Comment: @Hal the definition given above has the advantage that the cardinality of $n=\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ in terms of sets, is equal to the natural number $n$ in the usual sense. In this way, we might as well just *define* the cardinality of any finite set to **be** the set $n$ as opposed to the less well-defined (at least before we've made the above construction) number.

Comment: @fgp re: transitive sets, in that example - if I got rid of A, then x would no longer be an element of B? Are elements always (non) transitive?

Comment: @DanielRust I see, that is much more convenient. But to make sure I understand correctly: if we stipulated 0={} would it follow that 2={{{}}} (even if it's an unconventional and less convenient definition)?

Comment: @Hal What do you mean by "Are elements always (non) transitive?". In terms of boxes, transitivity means: Whenever some box contains another box, it also contains the contents of that box. Actually, your boxes are more than merely transitive, they are also hereditary transitive. A box is hereditary transitive if it's transitive and all the boxes contained in it are also transitive. Of course, since your boxes are all either empty, or contain other boxes (i.e. your universe contains only boxes), that's the same as saying all the boxes are transitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all structure is given by what each box contains, they are just sets: $A = ∅, B = \{A\}, C = \{A, B\}, D = \{A, B, C\}$. And they also corresponds to standard construction of natural numbers: $A = ∅ = 0, B = \{0\} = 1, C = \{0, 1\} = 2, D = \{0, 1, 2\} = 3$.